# operation is not allowed when the object is closed using vb6

Tags: excel, vb6

I have an excel file which brings the data from a stored procedure, it works perfect, now I've changed the stored procedure by another one with the same parameters that the old one, but I'm getting an error: "operation is not allowed when the object is closed", at the loop: Do While Not rsData.EOF

What in the world is happening here:

```
Set dbConnection = New ADODB.Connection
 dbConnection.ConnectionString = connStr
 dbConnection.ConnectionTimeout = 60
 dbConnection.Open

 Set Cmd = New ADODB.Command
 Cmd.CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdStoredProc
 Cmd.ActiveConnection = dbConnection
 Dim myrealenddate As Date

 'Create 2 output parameters
 Set pm1 = Cmd.CreateParameter("@DateIni", adDBDate, adParamInput, 15, CDate(Sheet1.TextBoxfechainiG))
 Set pm2 = Cmd.CreateParameter("@DateEnd", adDBDate, adParamInput, 15, CDate(Sheet1.TextBoxfechaendG))

 'Append the output parameters to command object
 Cmd.Parameters.Append pm1
 Cmd.Parameters.Append pm2
 Cmd.CommandText = "spProductionReportByDate"
 'Cmd.CommandText = "sp_Report_Recv_Metrics"

 Set rsData = New ADODB.Recordset
 Set rsData.Source = Cmd
 rsData.Open

 I = 4
 Do While Not rsData.EOF
  I = I + 1
  Sheet1.Range("A" & I).Value = rsData(0)
  Sheet1.Range("B" & I).Value = rsData(1)
  Sheet1.Range("C" & I).Value = rsData(2)
  Sheet1.Range("D" & I).Value = rsData(3)
  Sheet1.Range("E" & I).Value = rsData(4)
  Sheet1.Range("F" & I).Value = rsData(5)
  Sheet1.Range("G" & I).Value = rsData(6)
  Sheet1.Range("H" & I).Value = rsData(7)
  rsData.MoveNext
 Loop
 rsData.Close
 dbConnection.Close
```

Comment: Apparently `rsData` never got opened.

Comment: indeed that's the reason, but how, rsData.Open

Comment: rsData.Open is probably erroring out. Find out what the error is and update your question.

Comment: Does spProductionReportByDate take exactly the same number and type of parameters as sp_Report_Recv_Metrics? Run both of them from SQL management studio with the data you are passing to confirm.

Comment: I don't understand, if I change the sp by the one commented, the same code works perfect, and both sp return data, it's been tested

Comment: If you use the other SP and everything works, the problem is not in your code.

Comment: both sp receive two datetime parameters, I check for rsData.State after open it and is 0

Comment: Does the connection user/credentials have the same permissions on both sprocs?

Comment: yes, they have the same permissions

Comment: You could try to turn on ODBC connection tracing and try to see what is different when it fails as compared to when it succeeds. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/274551

Comment: ok, I disregard an issue with the code, is something related with the SP, but I'm not sure what could it be, like I said, both have the same parameters and type, and both have data.

Comment: replace the body of the sproc that doesn't work with the sproc that does work and run it. If it fails then it's not the code in the stored procedure its something about using a different stored procedure itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a long headache, I found the problem. Like I said, it was something related with the SPs, the only difference between the good SP and the bad SP was this line:

SET NOCOUNT ON

My god, that was the error's root cause, once added to the bad SP, it worked!

thanks a lot @Shane Wealti